# Updating conda in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I wanted to update my conda using "conda update conda" command but I've got the below error:

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
>
> UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.
> channel name: pkgs/main
> channel url: https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
> error code: 403
>
> You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
> Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
> and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.

What can I do?

Comment: are you in a vpn perhaps? With a `https_proxy` environment variable? If so, make sure the _value_ of this variable is `http://some-proxy` (not `https`).

Answer (score 1):

I solved an issue showing that error message changing my *.condarc* file.
Here is how my configuration now looks like:

```
$ conda config --show-sources
==> /home/<user>/.condarc <==
auto_activate_base: False
channels:
  - main
  - conda-forge
```